# ggplot2 mean symbol in boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following data:

```
GENDER Addressee_gender_and_age likelihood
 Female                      F20          4
 Female                      F20          5
   Male                      F20          3
 Female                      F20          3
 Female                      F20          4
   Male                      F20          1
```

I am interested in getting the boxplot

```
p = ggplot(data = melteddata, aes(x=Addressee_gender_and_age, y=likelihood)) +
  ggtitle("Distribution of the likelihood of complaining by gender") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=GENDER))
p + facet_wrap( ~ Addressee_gender_and_age, scales="free") +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)
```

The problem is the mean symbol is given for the entire wrap as follows:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the wrong value set as the x axis. I first create a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then change `aes(x=age, y=x)` to `aes(x=gender, y=x)` In your example it would be `GENDER` instead of `Addressee_gender_and_age`

```
Test<-data.frame(x=rnorm(40),age=rep(c(10,20,30,40,50),8),
                 gender=rep(c("Male","Female"),20))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = Test, aes(x=age, y=x)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=gender))+ 
  facet_wrap( ~ age, scales="free") +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = Test, aes(x=gender, y=x)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=gender))+ 
  facet_wrap( ~ age, scales="free") +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="darkred", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=3,show_guide = FALSE)
```

[image]